# MySQL: Insert new record by using the max value of the same column in same table

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I need to INSERT a new record, using the MAX value of the city_id column plus one, in the newly inserted row. So if the MAX value is 14, the next inserted row's city_id column value should be 15.

In my code, I will get the max value for the city_id column and then I am saving it. I am using a transaction for that code. I have two queries for it. But first you can see the code that I implemented below:

```
  private void saveCityDetail(final CityBO googleCityBO) {
    if (googleCityBO.getId() == null) {
      final Long cityId = cityMasterRepository.findMaxCityId();
      googleCityBO.setCityId(cityId + 1);
      googleCityBO.setActive(true);
    }
    cityMasterRepository.save(cityEntityBOMapper.convertCityBOToCityEntity(googleCityBO));
  }
```

Query1: Suppose there it two requests and both get the max value before saving it then there are two rows with same city id. I know about the different isolation levels in the transaction from which one is read. According to o my understanding If there is one transaction happening then other transactions can't read the data on the same row. Now it is the max value so will it also lock that row.

If transaction locking the row to read in the transaction level so it means it blocking the code to complete the first transaction it means we are achieving the synchronization also. I am confused please help me out or share some good blog te get a better understanding.

Query2: Suppose Everything is working fine that mention in the above query by using the transaction level or doing synchronization. Now my second query is on multiple instances. because I am doing it on a code level so two instances have two different transactions. so what will happen in that case both the transaction read the same max value and create two rows with the same city id.

please share the views on the above queries and how can we perform the above operation on multiple instances without any loophole.

Comment: `Insert Into TABLE (COLUMN, COLUMN) Values(Select Max(COLUMN) + 1 From TABLE, :PARAM)`

Comment: @Zorglube Thanks, Could you please explain the understanding of queries.